# How to properly pass custom data attribute props to child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, custom-data-attribute

Basically I have 3 custom attributes `data-pageName`, `data-defaultOption`, `data-options`.

The problem I have is that when I pass into my child component I get an unexpected token error because its something like this:

```
const pageContent = ({data-pageName, name, onChange, data-defaultOption, value, data-options}) => {
/*return here*/
};
```

Basically the `-` symbol is causing the error.

How do I include it as `data-pageName` and not read as `data` `-` `pageName`?

This is how I call the component:

```
<pageContent data-pageName={this.state.pageClicked} onChange={this.closeMenu} data-defaultOption={this.state.tmpDefaultOption} value={this.state.tmpValue} data-error={this.state.tmpError} data-options='a'/>
```

Comment: How do you call `pageContent`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dashes are not allowed in variable names. So, you have to use quotes `''`

```js
const Example = (props) =>
  <div>{props['data-name']}</div>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data-name="hello"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 8):

When you destruct your child component props, you can assign its dashed variables to  variables with [new names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

```
const PageContent = ({ 'data-options': dataOptions }) => (
    <div>...</div>
);

PageContent.propTypes = {
    'data-options': PropTypes.string
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

When using dashes, you must wrap it inside single quotes.

```
render() { 
  const myProps = {
    'data-pageName': this.state.pageClicked,
    'data-defaultOption': this.state.tmpDefaultOption,
  };

  return <MyComponent {...myProps} />
}
```

You can then use `this.props['data-pageName']` inside your child component.